# Naming convention uploaded files

Tags: php, file-upload, naming-conventions

On my site I let users upload files.

If the file is valid and uploaded it is moved to a folder (using PHP).

All users upload to the same folder.

I think I need to rename the uploaded files.

Is there something like a default naming convention to let users upload files with the same filename?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are no standard conventions, but there a couple of best-practices:

---

## Organizing your files into (User and/or Date) Aware Folders

Something like:

```
/uploads/USER/ or
/uploads/[USER/]YEAR/[MONTH/[DAY/[HOUR/[MINUTE/]]]]
```

This will have some benefits:

- organize files per user and/or date
- make it harder to reach the [maximum number of files per directory](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=maximum%20files%20per%20directory)

---

## (Not) Renaming / Sanitizing Filenames

Renaming or not is a choice you will have to make, depending on your website, user base, how obscure you would like to be and, obviously your architecture. Would you prefer to have a file named [`kate_at_the_beach.jpg`](http://www.google.com/search?q=kate%20at%20the%20beach&tbm=isch) or [`1304357611.jpg`](http://www.google.com/search?q=1304357611&tbm=isch)? This is really up to you to decide, but search engines (obviouslly) like the first one better.

One thing you should do is **always sanitize *and normalize* the filenames**, personally I would only allow the following chars: `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_`, `-`, `.` - if you choose this sanitation alphabet. normalization basically means just converting the filename to either lower or upper case (to avoid losing files if for instance you switch from a case sensitive file-system to a case insensitive one, like Windows).

Here is some sample code I use in **[phunction](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/)** (shameless plug, I know **:P**):

```
$filename = '/etc/hosts/@Álix Ãxel likes - beer?!.jpg';
$filename = Slug($filename, '_', '.'); // etc_hosts_alix_axel_likes_beer.jpg

function Slug($string, $slug = '-', $extra = null)
{
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z' . preg_quote($extra, '~') . ']+~i', $slug, Unaccent($string)), $slug));
}

function Unaccent($string) // normalizes (romanization) accented chars
{
    if (strpos($string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '&') !== false)
    {
        $string = html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $string;
}
```

---

## Handling Duplicate Filenames

As the documentation entry on [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) states:

> If the destination file already
>   exists, it will be overwritten.

So, before you call `move_uploaded_file()` you better check if the file already exists, if it does then you should (if you don't want to lose your older file) rename your new file, usually appending a time / random / unique token ***before*** the file extension, doing something like this:

```
if (file_exists($output . $filename) === true)
{
    $token = '_' . time(); // see below
    $filename = substr_replace($filename, $token, strrpos($filename, '.'), 0);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$input]['tmp_name'], $output . $filename);
```

This will have the effect of inserting the `$token` before the file extension, like I stated above. As for the choice of the `$token` value you have several options:

- **`time()`** - ensures uniqueness every second but sucks handling duplicate files
- **random** - not a very good idea, since it doesn't ensure uniqueness and doesn't handle duplicates
- **unique** - using an hash of the file ***contents*** is my favorite approach, since it guarantees ***content*** uniqueness and saves you HD space since you'll only have at most 2 identical files (one with the original filename and another one with the hash appended), sample code:

<sub>*(Dummy text so that the next line gets formatted as code.)*</sub>

```
$token = '_' . md5_file($_FILES[$input]['tmp_name']);
```

---

Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Especially the file limit per folder. And I really like the idea of creating file-hashes.

Comment: Just a great answer!

Answer (score 3):

There is no such convention, but usually, the name is randomly generated to make guessing less probable. Allowing the filename without sanitizing is strongly discouraged, take at least a whitelist approach in which you remove all characters except for those in the whitelist. The key is security, uploading is a risky feature and can be dangerous if not properly handled.

Answer (score 2):

Just make some convention internally yourself. You could for example just store the files as `userId_timestamp` in the folder, and keep the original filename in some database. Or you just make it `userId_originalFilename` or some other combination of things that make it unique.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar case, I save the info in a table (with the user ID as foreign key), format the autonumeric ID with leading zeroes for the filename (ie 000345.jpg) and store the original name in the table.

Comment: Of course this is for a 'reasonable' amount of files. If not, you could use some higher level grouping folders, like username or user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use some combination of the user's name and the upload date?